# R ggplot2 center align a multi-line title

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have a title that goes

```
... +
ggtitle('Something\nSomething Else\nSomething Else')
```

Is there any way I can get each line to center align rather than left align in the center?

```
...+
theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

gives me text in the center, but left aligned.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

would this work for you,

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)

DF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(400))
m <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram()
m + labs(title = "Vehicle \n Weight-Gas \n Mileage Relationship \n 
                 and some really long so that you can seee it's centered") + 
     theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

sorry about the typos in the plot title …

Comment: Hi @EricFail thanks that works. I hadn't noticed but my issue is more specific. It seems the problem only arises when I use `ggtitle(expression(italic(somthing\nsomething else)))` but that wasn't what I asked. thanks for your answer.

Comment: plotmath and multiline don't mix, that's why you had the issue with your expression.

Comment: For details, you can check this [article](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Titles_(ggplot2)/)